# Can we create Data Studio reports using Python?

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I am trying to automate the process of getting data from Big Query tables and creating a report in Data studio. Is there any python code, APIs or some other method which will be able to address this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, You can create and google spreadsheet which is updated using python and then link that sheet with data studio when the data in google sheet is updated data in datastudio will be updated automatically you can use pygsheets module to update the google sheets

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Data Studio templates](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/report-templates) but it might be too restrictive for what you trying to do.